# Trying to get property of non-object when using Auth in service provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get an error 'Trying to get property of non-object' in my service provider when I used Auth :

```
public function boot()
{

    $roles = DB::table('folders')->orderBy('folder_id', 'desc')->where('level', 0)->get();
    if(Auth::user()->level == 1){
        $roles1 = DB::table('folders')->orderBy('folder_id', 'asc')->where('level', 1)->get();
    }else{
        $user = DB::table('folder_permissions')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach($user as $u){
            $roles1 = DB::table('folders')->orderBy('folder_id', 'asc')->where('level', 1)->get();
        }
    }

    $treeFolder = DB::table('folders')->where('level', 0)->get();
    if(!empty($treeFolder)){
        foreach($treeFolder as $folders){
            $arrayCategories[$folders->folder_id] = array("parent_id" => $folders->parent, "name" => array("fname" => $folders->folder_name, "id" => $folders->folder_id));
        }
    }else{
        $arrayCategories = FALSE;  
    }

    view()->share(['folder' => $roles, 'prime_folders' => $roles1, 'treeView' => $arrayCategories]);
}
```

I already called 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;', but nothing happen.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that, Auth is loading before everything get ready. you just follow this, it works

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
{

    $roles = DB::table('folders')->orderBy('folder_id', 'desc')->where('level', 0)->get();
    if(Auth::user()->level == 1){
        $roles1 = DB::table('folders')->orderBy('folder_id', 'asc')->where('level', 1)->get();
    }else{
        $user = DB::table('folder_permissions')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach($user as $u){
            $roles1 = DB::table('folders')->orderBy('folder_id', 'asc')->where('level', 1)->get();
        }
    }

    $treeFolder = DB::table('folders')->where('level', 0)->get();
    if(!empty($treeFolder)){
        foreach($treeFolder as $folders){
            $arrayCategories[$folders->folder_id] = array("parent_id" => $folders->parent, "name" => array("fname" => $folders->folder_name, "id" => $folders->folder_id));
        }
    }else{
        $arrayCategories = FALSE;  
    }

    //if this line doesn't work then.... see below line after this coming up line
    $view->share(['folder' => $roles, 'prime_folders' => $roles1, 'treeView' => $arrayCategories]);  

    $view->with('folder', $roles)->with('prime_folders',$roles1)->with('treeView',$arrayCategories);  
});
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 17: syntax error, unexpected 'view' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: Which line you used in your code. `$view->share` or `$view->with`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake .. It is work now, thank you ..
would you tell me what is this mean 'view()->composer('*', function ($view)' ? And can I put that code anywhere I want or it just work in service provider ? 

Sorry for my poor english.
I'm new in laravel

Comment: Here is the official documentation link, I am sure this will help you alot [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)
mark my answer, so other can take benefits too. :)